# What is the rule that browsers follow when attempting to render custom fonts?

Tags: css, fonts

I have a couple questions about how browsers attempt to render custom fonts. Hopefully the answers to these questions will help me resolve the problem I'm having right now.

Suppose I have an `@font-face` declaration

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'museo_700regular';
    src: url('some-font.eot');
    src: url('some-font-iefix.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('some-font.woff') format('woff'),
         url('some-font.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('some-font.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

1. Does the browser try to read/render `some-font.eot`, and if it doesn't work, tries `some-font-iefix.eot`, etc.?
2. If there are conflicting `@font-face` declarations between CSS files, does the browsers try to read the last one?
3. What if the previous one was read/rendered properly and the second is invalid: Does the browser stay with the first one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the browser try to read/render `some-font.eot`, and if it doesn't work, tries `some-font-iefix.eot`, etc.?

**Sorta**. Different browsers support different types of fonts. Browsers determine which one(s) it knows how to render, and then download and use that one.

---

> if there are conflicting `@font-face` declarations between CSS files, does the browsers try to read the last one?

**Yes**. CSS is always hierarchical. If the furthest down declaration is the one that will be used.

---

> What if the previous one was read/rendered properly and the second is invalid: Does the browser stay with the first one?

Assuming the CSS is syntactically valid, **no**. If it's invalid, it will not override the previous declarations (because the browser won't know what to do with it).